# How to scrape all information on a web page after the id = "firstheading" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all text from a web page (using python) that comes after the first heading . The tag for that heading is : `<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">Albert Einstein</h1>`

I don't want any information before this heading . I want to scrape all text written after this heading . Can I use BeautifulSoup in python for this ?

I am running the following code :
` *

```
import requests
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urlpage = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Publications'
res = requests.get(urlpage)
soup1 = (bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')).get_text()
 print(soup1)
```

` *

The web page has the following information :

```
Albert Einstein - Wikipedia
document.documentElement.className="client-js";RLCONF={"wgCanonicalNamespace":"","wgCanonicalSpecialPageName":!1,"wgNamespaceNumber":0,"wgPageName":"Albert_Einstein","wgTitle":"Albert Einstein","wgCurRevisionId":920687884,"wgRevisionId":920687884,"wgArticleId":736,"wgIsArticle":!0,"wgIsRedirect":!1,"wgAction":"view","wgUserName":null,"wgUserGroups":["*"],"wgCategories":["Pages with missing ISBNs","Webarchive template wayback links","CS1 German-language sources (de)","CS1: Julian–Gregorian uncertainty","CS1 French-language sources (fr)","CS1 errors: missing periodical","CS1: long volume value","Wikipedia indefinitely semi-protected pages","Use American English from February 2019","All Wikipedia articles written in American English","Articles with short description","Good articles","Articles containing German-language text","Biography with signature","Articles with hCards","Articles with hAudio microformats","All articles with unsourced statements",
"Articles with unsourced statements from July 2019","Commons category link from Wikidata","Articles with Wikilivres links","Articles with Curlie links","Articles with Project Gutenberg links","Articles with Internet Archive links","Articles with LibriVox links","Use dmy dates from August 2019","Wikipedia articles with BIBSYS identifiers","Wikipedia articles with BNE identifiers","Wikipedia articles with BNF identifiers","Wikipedia articles with GND identifiers","Wikipedia articles with HDS identifiers","Wikipedia articles with ISNI identifiers","Wikipedia articles with LCCN identifiers","Wikipedia articles with LNB identifiers","Wikipedia articles with MGP identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NARA identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NCL identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NDL identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NKC identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NLA identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NLA-person identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NLI identifiers",
"Wikipedia articles with NLR identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NSK identifiers","Wikipedia articles with NTA identifiers","Wikipedia articles with SBN identifiers","Wikipedia articles with SELIBR identifiers","Wikipedia articles with SNAC-ID identifiers","Wikipedia articles with SUDOC identifiers","Wikipedia articles with ULAN identifiers","Wikipedia articles with VIAF identifiers","Wikipedia articles with WorldCat-VIAF identifiers","AC with 25 elements","Wikipedia articles with suppressed authority control identifiers","Pages using authority control with parameters","Articles containing timelines","Pantheists","Spinozists","Albert Einstein","1879 births","1955 deaths","20th-century American engineers","20th-century American writers","20th-century German writers","20th-century physicists","American agnostics","American inventors","American letter writers","American pacifists","American people of German-Jewish descent","American physicists","American science writers",
"American socialists","American Zionists","Ashkenazi Jews","Charles University in Prague faculty","Corresponding Members of the Russian Academy of Sciences (1917–25)","Cosmologists","Deaths from abdominal aortic aneurysm","Einstein family","ETH Zurich alumni","ETH Zurich faculty","German agnostics","German Jews","German emigrants to Switzerland","German Nobel laureates","German inventors","German physicists","German socialists","European democratic socialists","Institute for Advanced Study faculty","Jewish agnostics","Jewish American scientists","Jewish emigrants from Nazi Germany to the United States","Jews who emigrated to escape Nazism","Jewish engineers","Jewish inventors","Jewish philosophers","Jewish physicists","Jewish socialists","Leiden University faculty","Foreign Fellows of the Indian National Science Academy","Foreign Members of the Royal Society","Members of the American Philosophical Society","Members of the Bavarian Academy of Sciences","Members of the Lincean Academy"
,"Members of the Royal Netherlands Academy of Arts and Sciences","Members of the United States National Academy of Sciences","Honorary Members of the USSR Academy of Sciences","Naturalised citizens of Austria","Naturalised citizens of Switzerland","New Jersey socialists","Nobel laureates in Physics","Patent examiners","People from Berlin","People from Bern","People from Munich","People from Princeton, New Jersey","People from Ulm","People from Zürich","People who lost German citizenship","People with acquired American citizenship","Philosophers of science","Relativity theorists","Stateless people","Swiss agnostics","Swiss emigrants to the United States","Swiss Jews","Swiss physicists","Theoretical physicists","Winners of the Max Planck Medal","World federalists","Recipients of the Pour le Mérite (civil class)","Determinists","Activists from New Jersey","Mathematicians involved with Mathematische Annalen","Intellectual Cooperation","Disease-related deaths in New Jersey"],
"wgBreakFrames":!1,"wgPageContentLanguage":"en","wgPageContentModel":"wikitext","wgSeparatorTransformTable":["",""],"wgDigitTransformTable":["",""],"wgDefaultDateFormat":"dmy","wgMonthNames":["","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"],"wgMonthNamesShort":["","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"],"wgRelevantPageName":"Albert_Einstein","wgRelevantArticleId":736,"wgRequestId":"XaChjApAICIAALSsYfgAAABV","wgCSPNonce":!1,"wgIsProbablyEditable":!1,"wgRelevantPageIsProbablyEditable":!1,"wgRestrictionEdit":["autoconfirmed"],"wgRestrictionMove":["sysop"],"wgMediaViewerOnClick":!0,"wgMediaViewerEnabledByDefault":!0,"wgPopupsReferencePreviews":!1,"wgPopupsConflictsWithNavPopupGadget":!1,"wgVisualEditor":{"pageLanguageCode":"en","pageLanguageDir":"ltr","pageVariantFallbacks":"en"},"wgMFDisplayWikibaseDescriptions":{"search":!0,"nearby":!0,"watchlist":!0,"tagline":
!1},"wgWMESchemaEditAttemptStepOversample":!1,"wgULSCurrentAutonym":"English","wgNoticeProject":"wikipedia","wgWikibaseItemId":"Q937","wgCentralAuthMobileDomain":!1,"wgEditSubmitButtonLabelPublish":!0};RLSTATE={"ext.globalCssJs.user.styles":"ready","site.styles":"ready","noscript":"ready","user.styles":"ready","ext.globalCssJs.user":"ready","user":"ready","user.options":"ready","user.tokens":"loading","ext.cite.styles":"ready","ext.math.styles":"ready","mediawiki.legacy.shared":"ready","mediawiki.legacy.commonPrint":"ready","jquery.makeCollapsible.styles":"ready","mediawiki.toc.styles":"ready","wikibase.client.init":"ready","ext.visualEditor.desktopArticleTarget.noscript":"ready","ext.uls.interlanguage":"ready","ext.wikimediaBadges":"ready","ext.3d.styles":"ready","mediawiki.skinning.interface":"ready","skins.vector.styles":"ready"};RLPAGEMODULES=["ext.cite.ux-enhancements","ext.cite.tracking","ext.math.scripts","ext.scribunto.logs","site","mediawiki.page.startup",
"mediawiki.page.ready","jquery.makeCollapsible","mediawiki.toc","mediawiki.searchSuggest","ext.gadget.teahouse","ext.gadget.ReferenceTooltips","ext.gadget.watchlist-notice","ext.gadget.DRN-wizard","ext.gadget.charinsert","ext.gadget.refToolbar","ext.gadget.extra-toolbar-buttons","ext.gadget.switcher","ext.centralauth.centralautologin","mmv.head","mmv.bootstrap.autostart","ext.popups","ext.visualEditor.desktopArticleTarget.init","ext.visualEditor.targetLoader","ext.eventLogging","ext.wikimediaEvents","ext.navigationTiming","ext.uls.compactlinks","ext.uls.interface","ext.cx.eventlogging.campaigns","ext.quicksurveys.init","ext.centralNotice.geoIP","ext.centralNotice.startUp","skins.vector.js"];
(RLQ=window.RLQ||[]).push(function(){mw.loader.implement("user.tokens@tffin",function($,jQuery,require,module){/*@nomin*/mw.user.tokens.set({"patrolToken":"+\\","watchToken":"+\\","csrfToken":"+\\"});
});});
```

> `Albert Einstein`
>
> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> Jump to navigation Jump to search "Einstein" redirects here. For other
>   people, see Einstein (surname). For other uses, see Albert Einstein
>   (disambiguation) and Einstein (disambiguation).
>
> German-born physicist and developer of the theory of relativity
>
> Albert EinsteinEinstein in 1921Born(1879-03-14)14 March 1879Ulm,
>   Kingdom of Württemberg, German EmpireDied18 April 1955(1955-04-18)
>   (aged 76)Princeton, New Jersey, United StatesResidenceGermany, Italy,
>   Switzerland, Austria (present-day Czech Republic), Belgium, United
>   StatesCitizenship Subject of the Kingdom of Württemberg during the
>   German Empire (1879–1896)[note 1] Stateless (1896–1901) Citizen of
>   Switzerland (1901–1955) Austrian subject of the Austro-Hungarian
>   Empire (1911–1912) Subject of the Kingdom of Prussia during the German
>   Empire (1914–1918)[note 1] German citizen of the Free State of Prussia
>   (Weimar Republic, 1918–1933) Citizen of the United States (1940–1955)
>   Education Federal polytechnic school (1896–1900; B.A., 1900)
>   University of Zurich (Ph.D., 1905) Known for General relativity
>   Special relativity Photoelectric effect E=mc2 (Mass–energy
>   equivalence) E=hf (Planck–Einstein relation) Theory of Brownian motion
>   Einstein field equations Bose–Einstein statistics Bose–Einstein
>   condensate Gravitational wave Cosmological constant Unified field
>   theory EPR paradox Ensemble interpretation List of other concepts
>   Spouse(s)Mileva Marić(m. 1903; div. 1919)Elsa Löwenthal(m. 1919;
>   died[1][2] 1936)Children"Lieserl" Einstein Hans Albert Einstein Eduard
>   "Tete" EinsteinAwards Barnard Medal (1920) Nobel Prize in Physics
>   (1921) Matteucci Medal (1921) ForMemRS (1921)[3] Copley Medal
>   (1925)[3] Gold Medal of the Royal Astronomical Society (1926) Max
>   Planck Medal (1929) Member of the National Academy of Sciences (1942)
>   Time Person of the Century (1999) Scientific careerFieldsPhysics,
>   philosophyInstitutions Swiss Patent Office (Bern) (1902–1909)
>   University of Bern (1908–1909) University of Zurich (1909–1911)
>   Charles University in Prague (1911–1912) ETH Zurich (1912–1914)
>   Prussian Academy of Sciences (1914–1933) Humboldt University of Berlin
>   (1914–1933) Kaiser Wilhelm Institute (director, 1917–1933) German
>   Physical Society (president, 1916–1918) Leiden University (visits,
>   1920) Institute for Advanced Study (1933–1955) Caltech (visits,
>   1931–1933) University of Oxford (visits, 1931–1933) ThesisEine neue
>   Bestimmung der Moleküldimensionen (A New Determination of Molecular
>   Dimensions) (1905)Doctoral advisorAlfred KleinerOther academic
>   advisorsHeinrich Friedrich WeberInfluences Arthur Schopenhauer Baruch
>   Spinoza Bernhard Riemann David Hume Ernst Mach Hendrik Lorentz Hermann
>   Minkowski Isaac Newton James Clerk Maxwell Michele Besso Moritz
>   Schlick Thomas Young Influenced Virtually all modern physics
>
> Signature Albert Einstein (/ˈaɪnstaɪn/ EYEN-styne;[4] German: [ˈalbɛʁt
>   ˈʔaɪnʃtaɪn] (listen); 14 March 1879 – 18 April 1955) was a German-born
>   theoretical physicist[5] who developed the theory of relativity, one
>   of the two pillars of modern physics (alongside quantum
>   mechanics).[3][6]:274 His work is also known for its influence on the
>   philosophy of science.[7][8] He is best known to the general public
>   for his mass–energy equivalence formula  . . . . .

I only want text after the first heading "Albert Einstein"

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible information?

Comment: which url data you want to scrape? in web scraping first you need to understand in which format html is arranged, even if you are using ```regex``` and ```bs4```

Comment: I have made an edit , sorry for inconvenience .

Comment: @AnkitChawla you need to provide your code trial what you have tried and as well your expected output? seems like you want to get  `Albert Einstein` this text?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @lagripe please review question , I have made edits

Comment: @KunduK , I have mad edits as to what I want please review the question .

Comment: Isn't there an API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find h1 tag and then use `find_next_siblings('div')` and print the text value.

```
import requests
import bs4

urlpage = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Publications'
res = requests.get(urlpage)
soup1 =bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
h1=soup1.find('h1')
for item in h1.find_next_siblings('div'):
    print(item.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to get the text such as described, I suggest a bit of an "non-parser" way.

By cutting the string directly from the response object.

Let's do this:

```py
import requests

urlpage = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein#Publications"
my_string = """<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">Albert Einstein</h1>""" # define the string you want

response = requests.get(urlpage).text # get the full response html as str
cut_response = response[response.find(my_string)::] # cut the str from your string on

soup1 = (bs4.BeautifulSoup(cut_response, 'lxml')).get_text() # get soup object, but of cut string
print(soup1)
```

Should work.